# Docker Compose using with git clone

Tags: git, apache, docker, github, docker-compose

I tried to do a clone via Git on my docker compose, but i'm just started using a docker and i don't know how can i do it.
I want to do a download inside de apache (document root) /var/www/html.
The line is: `command: bash -c "git clone git@github.com:user/project.git"`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0.21
      command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      restart: always
      container_name: mysql
      environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_USER=user
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
          - MYSQL_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=1024M
          - MYSQL_INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE=1G
          - MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE=256M
          - MYSQL_INNODB_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE=256M
      ports:
          - '3361:3360'
      volumes:
          - "./docker/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    apache:
      image: php:7.4.11-apache
      restart: always
      container_name: apache
      ports:
        - '8081:80'
        - '443:8443'
      volumes:
        - ./docker/www:/var/www/html
      command: bash -c "git clone git@github.com:user/project.git"
      environment:
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_enable=1 remote_host=192.168.15.21 remote_port=8081 remote_autostart=1"
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      links:
        - mysql
    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin:latest
      restart: always
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      environment:
        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      volumes:
        - "./docker/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php"
```

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: @PrateekNaik apache exited with code 127

Comment: Especially since you're bind-mounting that directory from the host, you can just run the `git` command there.  You can add some artifacts like this `docker-compose.yml` file and the `Dockerfile` you need to build your custom image into the root of the repository as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@GustavoFilgueiras The reason you are encountering an error is because the image `php:7.4.11-apache` that you are utilizing for your `apache` service does not come with `git` preinstalled. Also, based on your feedback, the following assumes you are attempting to connect to a private repo and the SSH key normally utilized is located in the default path `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (please update this in `docker-compose.yml` if not the case). You have two options to resolve it:

1. (Recommended) Create a new custom image by utilizing `php:7.4.11-apache` as a base image. This brings the benefit of adding this dependency directly into the image so that startup times do not experience unnecessary delays. To do this, you need to create a `Dockerfile` within the same directory like so:

```
FROM php:7.4.11-apache
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install git -y && \
  ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Then you may modify your `apache` service in your `docker-compose.yml` like so:

```yaml
    apache:
      build: .
      restart: always
      container_name: apache
      ports:
        - '8081:80'
        - '443:8443'
      volumes:
        - ./docker/www:/var/www/html
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa
      command: bash -c "git clone git@github.com:user/project.git"
      environment:
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_enable=1 remote_host=192.168.15.21 remote_port=8081 remote_autostart=1"
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      links:
        - mysql
```

2. Include multiple commands within your `docker-compose.yml`. This will not require any additional files but the result adds unnecessary delays in startup times as `git` dependency will need to be installed each time. For instance, your `apache` service in your `docker-compose.yml` could look like this:

```yaml
    apache:
      image: php:7.4.11-apache
      restart: always
      container_name: apache
      ports:
        - '8081:80'
        - '443:8443'
      volumes:
        - ./docker/www:/var/www/html
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa
      command: 
        - bash
        - -c
        - >
          apt-get update;
          apt-get install git -y;
          ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts;
          git clone git@github.com:user/project.git;
      environment:
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_enable=1 remote_host=192.168.15.21 remote_port=8081 remote_autostart=1"
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      links:
        - mysql
```

Comment: It's almost work....
I think i have a problem with my ida_rsa key

Comment: apache exited with code 128
apache        | Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
apache        | Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
apache        | Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease

Comment: apache        | Reading package lists...
apache        | Reading package lists...
apache        | Building dependency tree...
apache        | Reading state information...
apache        | git is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3).
apache        | The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:

Comment: apache        |   sensible-utils
apache        | Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
apache        | 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
apache        | Cloning into 'myRepo'...

Comment: apache        | Host key verification failed.
apache        | fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
apache        |
apache        | Please make sure you have the correct access rights
apache        | and the repository exists.

Comment: @GustavoFilgueiras Is the GitHub repo you are trying to access public or private? Notice in the `clone` statement I shared I modified it from using `git@...` (ssh method) to `https://...` (https method). I have assumed it is public which is therefore best to use https as it doesn't require any additional config or shell input. If private, let me know and I can update the answer. Also, once you find my answer works for you, would you accept it as your answer?

Comment: Is it a prive repo.

Comment: @GustavoFilgueiras Based on your feedback, I have updated the answer for a private repo. Let me know if the answer is now sufficient and can be accepted.

Comment: unfourtunetly dosen't work... but its ok, you already help me a lot.